# Getting all four Batch Normalization parameters for inference in CNTK

Tags: cntk

The two Batch Normalization (BN) parameters that you get from the parameters() function are insufficient for inference. BN computes y = gamma * (x – E[x]) / Var[x]) + beta. How do get access to the other two?

Answer (score 0):

The other 2 (mean and variance statistics) are “constants” since they are not trained using gradients using SGD. You can get to them by calling ‘constants’.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `cntk.layers.BatchNormalization` layer and name the layer, then the parameters can be accessed by name:

```
>>> y=BatchNormalization(name='bn')
>>> y.bn.scale
Parameter('scale', [], [?])
>>> y.bn.bias
Parameter('bias', [], [?])
>>> y.bn.aggregate_mean
Constant('aggregate_mean', [], [?])
>>> y.bn.aggregate_variance
Constant('aggregate_variance', [], [?])
>>> y.bn.aggregate_count
Constant('aggregate_count', [], [])
```

Note that these are aggregates that are formed during training for purpose of being used during inference. There is no way to access a single minibatch's mean and variance during training.